# how to use functions written in someother worksheets in MAPLE

Tags: maple

I have just started to use MAPLE. I am a matlab user.

In matlab I can use any matlab function(.m file) written in same directory.

Could someone help me out how I can do same with MAPLE. I have few worksheets performing some tasks(all in same directory)

I need to use those functions and write my own code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: From Maple documents it mentioned through classes we can call methods. But, It is realy not useful https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=object/methods

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [packages](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=module%2Fpackage)? They use the same module structure as objects, but for a different purpose - they are meant to make code reusable.

A package can be maintained as source file and then be read from the current directory by its filename: `read("MyModule.mpl")`. This seems similar to what you are used from matlab, except that you would have to load the module explicitly. Alternatively it can be saved as binary *.mla file (Maple library archive) somewhere on the library path, then loaded by its exported package name from anywhere: `with(MyModul)`.